# Is it possible to schedule Map Reduce jobs on specific slave nodes?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, bigdata, hadoop2

Is it possible to schedule any map reduce job on some specific nodes, instead of all nodes, in a Hadoop cluster? Say for example, on 4 slave nodes out of 10 available nodes. I tried searching on Google but didn't find any relevant result. [This page](https://www.inkling.com/read/hadoop-definitive-guide-tom-white-3rd/chapter-6/job-scheduling) says that by default all the jobs get scheduled on the complete cluster.

Reason of my requirement:

I have to implement a distributed relational database as a graduate level assignment work. I am using Hadoop and as per the assignment requirement we have to replicate data to the connected machines of the cluster. Now one of our replication model asks to run the query on a subset of available machines.

Comment: I'm intrigued as to why you'd want to do this!

Comment: @chiastic-security I have added the reason. Please help you have any idea/relevant idea.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/FAQ#I_want_to_make_a_large_cluster_smaller_by_taking_out_a_bunch_of_nodes_simultaneously._How_can_this_be_done.3F You can also do the same process for the tasktrackers.

Comment: @vefthym not completely. but it will help.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose to process some data on hadoop cluster ,you have submitted  a map reduce job ,now what it does is  job tracker which plays the role of a master by assigning ,monitoring and coordinating  different tasks for different task tracker.

Job tracker will talk to namenode which is again play role of a master , for the data which need to be processed ,since namenode holds all the information of a  metadata ,so it would provide all the information where that particular data in residing in terms of which block is residing at which datanode to job tracker.

As a part of hadoop framework job tracker  would invoke the task tracker of those datanodes where your data blocks are located ,worst scenario task tracker of that node where is closest to the datanode where some of the data blocks are there.

So summary is you we can't control which particular machines would be used that would depend where your data blocks are residing for that particular job. if it is located in 4 machines so at that moment 4 machines would be used if 10 then 10 would be used